# How do I make my alert disappear?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I've created an alert using Bootstrap in my Django project. The problem is, I can't seem to make it disappear when I click on the x. I followed the instructions on the bootstrap website as well as I could, but they aren't particularly helpful.

I have the following errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined
at index.js:21

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).alert is not a function
at (index):79
```

And the following code:

Header.html:

```
{% block header %}
<head>
    <title>Elect</title>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type='text/css'/>

</head>
{% endblock %}

<body>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src={% static "js/bootstrap.min.js" %}></script>

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}

</body>
```

Ballot.html:

```
{% extends 'header.html' %}

{% block content %}


<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <h4>Error!</h4><p>Invalid Submission</p>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(".alert").alert('close')

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

What do I need to do to make the alert remove button work?

Comment: Try $(".alert").hide();

Comment: maybe bootstrap js is not loaded, instead of `<script src={% static "js/bootstrap.min.js" %}></script>` try `<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>`

Comment: Try using `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` or include PopperJs separately.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in jQuery Ready

```
$(function() {
    $(".alert").alert('close')
});
```

Also, move your js file below and put it before `</body>`

Comment: I made both your amendments, but I still have the following errors:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined
    at index.js:21`
and
`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).alert is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):82)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.I (jquery.min.js:2)`

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 depends on Popper.js for dropdown/tooltip/popover components. I know here you don't use one of these components but it's a dependancy so you have to include it.

A link to download Popper.js : https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js

But since our latest release (Beta 2) you'll find two new files *bootstrap.bundle.js* and *bootstrap.bundle.min.js* which contains Bootstrap + Popper.js : https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js

For your jQuery issue maybe you should try that :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" integrity="sha384-E7gp+UYBLS2XewcxoJbfi0UpGMHSvt9XyI9bH4YIw5GDGW8AlC+2J7bVBBlMFC6p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```